# Кто-нибудь, объясните подробно как этот код проверяет простое ли число?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def is_prime(n):   
    return ~-2 ** n % n < 2
```

Comment: Для числа 341 выдаёт неверный результат. Вообще нельзя за константное время для произвольного числа узнать достоверно простое число или нет. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B

Comment: причиной широкого использования простых чисел в криптографии является трудность обнаружения этих чисел.не существует такой формулы.

Comment: Никак не проверяет. Откуда Вы взяли это? Можно источник, пожалуйста?